# Rotate a vector until it is perpendicular to another

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations, rotations

Let $x, y\in\mathbb{R}^n$. I would like to rotate $y$ so that it is perpendicular to $x$. Is it possible to find a matrix $R\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ that does that?

$$
x^\top Ry = 0
$$

## Attempt

The matrix must be orthogonal $RR^\top =I$. This means we must have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n r_{ik} r_{jk} = \delta_{ij} \qquad \forall i,j\in\{1, \ldots, n\}
$$
Since $RR^\top$ is symmetric, we must have that the above and below diagonal entries are the same, thus they would lead to the same constraints. Overall we have $n$ diagonal and $\frac{1}{2}n(n-1)$ off-diagonal constraints for a total of $\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$ constraints. In addition, we also have the constraints given by the condition that $y'=Ry$ is perpendicular to $x$
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n x_i R_{ij} y_j = 0 
$$
Thus we have $\frac{1}{2}n^2 + \frac{1}{2}n + 1$ constraints. One final constrain, in order for $R$ to be a proper rotation, is given by the determinant $\det(R) = 1$, which gives one more constraint. Overall we have
$$
\frac{1}{2}n^2 + \frac{1}{2}n + 2
$$
constraints. However, $R$ has $n^2$ entries.

Comment: Note: I have also access to some vector $z\perp x$ so in case I am happy with any answer that gives me $Ry$ parallel to $z$

Comment: Just take a rotation in the plane spanned by $y$ and $z$, mapping $y$ to $z$ (up to scaling).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, find the orthogonal projection of $y$ onto the line spanned by $x$ - call it $\hat y$. This amounts to saying $\hat y=u(y\cdot u)$, where $u=x/\|x\|$, the unit vector for that line. The matrix for this is

$$P=\begin{bmatrix}u_1^2&u_1u_2&u_1u_3&\cdots\\u_2u_1&u_2^2&u_2u_3&\cdots\\u_3u_1&u_3u_2&u_3^2&\cdots\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\cdots\end{bmatrix}$$

Such that $\hat y=Py$. Now, the projection onto the orthogonal complement of this is $I-P$. $I$ denotes the identity matrix. From now on, $\hat y$ refers to the orthogonal projection of $y$ onto the orthogonal complement of the line spanned by $x$. This will orthogonally project $y$ onto a line orthogonal to $x$, but we need a rotation of $y$ - we must make it the same length. So we need to rescale by $\|y\|/\|\hat y\|$. The length of this new orthogonal projection, $\hat y=(I-P)y$, is calculated as follows:

$$\|(I-P)y\|=\|y-Py\|=\|y-u(y\cdot u)\|$$

I don’t know how to make a single matrix to accomplish this, but very simply we can say $x^T(I-P)y=0$, and to make this a proper rotation we scale $(I-P)y$ by $\|y\|/\|(I-P)y\|$.

Concrete example:

$$x=\begin{pmatrix}2\\4\\5\end{pmatrix},\,y=\begin{pmatrix}2\\1\\2\end{pmatrix},\|x\|=3\sqrt{5},\,\|y\|=3\\u=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{2}{3\sqrt{5}}\\\frac{4}{3\sqrt{5}}\\\frac{\sqrt{5}}{3}\end{pmatrix}\\P=\frac{1}{45}\begin{pmatrix}4&8&10\\8&16&20\\10&20&25\end{pmatrix}\\I-P=\frac{1}{45}\begin{pmatrix}41&-8&-10\\-8&29&-20\\-10&-20&20\end{pmatrix}\\\hat y=(I-P)y=\frac{1}{45}\begin{pmatrix}54\\-27\\0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{6}{5}\\-\frac{3}{5}\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

And $\hat y$ is orthogonal to $x$, but is not the same length as $y$, so the rescale is necessary.

Comment: I am a bit confused, is $P$ equal to $u u^\top$?

Comment: $P$ is constructed as the matrix that does the following operation on its input: $Py=u(y\cdot u)$, which you can verify if you study $P$’s construction closely. This results on orthogonally projecting $y$ onto the line spanned by $u$ (the same line spanned by $x$). Then $(I-P)$ orthogonally projects onto *the set of all lines orthogonal to $x$*, more precisely the “orthogonal complement” of $x$. However, a projection will usually change the length of its input vector $y$, which is why I say we rescale at the end. Then, you’ll have a vector, same length as $y$, that is orthogonal to $x$.

Comment: thank you so much for this, this works perfectly! I was just wondering if you think it would be possible to find an alternative (but equivalent) rotation matrix?

Comment: @Physics_Student So what I did was not a rotation matrix, since rotation in multiple dimensions I felt was tricky to quantify. What I did was create an *orthogonal projection*, which is a very useful thing to know in linear algebra, so that $z=Py$ would lie on the span on your line - $x$ - and then importantly $(I-P)y=\hat y$ would be orthogonal to the line $x$; in general, if $P$ is an orthogonal projection onto a set, $(I-P)$ is an orthogonal projection onto the “*orthogonal complement*” of that set, which here just means anywhere perpendicular to $x$

Comment: It is *not* a rotation because it doesn’t preserve length - which is why a rescale is needed. Multidimensional rotation is tricky, and I assume one would need to take the arccosine of a dot product and then figure out how to rotate a line along a plane that $x$ and $y$ lie on and my solution is computationally easier than that!

Comment: makes sense! Got it, you projeted it and then you rescaled it so that it would be the same size as before. I love this solution with the projection but basically in what I am trying to do, I would like to somehow find a different kind of matrix $R$ achieving the same goal.

Comment: ooh I see thank you! The function $y\mapsto (I-P)y$ is not a rotation. But isn't the function $y\mapsto \frac{\|y\|}{\|(I-P)y\|}(I-P)y$ a rotation since it preserves length?

Comment: I feel like, technically speaking, one still wouldn’t call it a rotation, but it achieves the same effect - on $y$. There is a small issue with the fact that it only works on $y$! I’ll do some research to see if there is a general true rotation solution but I’m not sure if such a thing would be easier or any better than the projection @Physics_Student

Comment: Thank you so much for looking into it. If there's some non-obvious keywords that you think might work let me know so I can also have a look!

Comment: See [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) and find the “In 3D: General Rotations” section. You’ll find that A) it requires a matrix multiplication of multiple matrices (with many calls to sine and cosine) and B) Wikipedia spend some time talking about projections, and in fact if you want to figure out the angle of $x$ from each axis using projections is the most natural way! @Physics_Student

Comment: “Quarternions” are sometimes used in favour of matrices for 3D rotation specifically.

Answer (score 0):

We are given $x$ and $y$, and we want to find $R$ such that $x^T R y = 0$.  Thus we must have the vector $y_1 = R y$ in the orthogonal space of vector $x$.

So the first step is to generate the orthogonal space to $x$ by solving the homogenous linear system $ x^T v = 0 $ for all possible $v$'s.  Let the matrix $V$ contain a basis of this orthogonal space, then we can select

$y_1 = V u $

for some $u \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1} $

Since rotation preserves length, then we have to scale $y_1$ to have the same length as $y$.

Next, the rotation matrix $R$ alters $y$ into $y_1 = R y$ but does not alter the vectors orthogonal to $y$ and $y_1$, so the next step is to find an orthogonal basis for the orthogonal complement to the two vectors {$y$, $y_1$}, and this can be done in two steps, first find a basis (not necessarily orthogonal) of the orthogonal complement to {$y$, $y_1$}, which will have dimension $n-2$.  In step two, you'll take these $n-2$ vectors and ammend them with the vectors $y$ and $y_1$, so that now you have a complete set of $n$ vectors.  Run the Gram-Schmidt process to orthogonalize them, and let the matrix containing the orthonormal vectors be $G$. Now express $y$ and $y_1$ in terms of these basis vectors.

$y = G w_1 $ and $y_1 = G w_2 $

Since the first $(n-2)$ vectors of $G$ are orthogonal to $y$ and $y_1$, then the first $(n-2)$ entries of $w_1$ and $w_2$ will be zero.

Let $p_1$ be the $2 \times 1$ vector of the last two entries of $w_1$ and $p_2$ be the $2 \times 1$ vector of the last two entries of $w_2$, then we can relate $p_2$ to $p_1$ by a rotation (remember they have the same length),

$p_2 = R_{22} p_1$

where $R_{22}$ is a $2 \times 2$ rotation matrix.  Finally define the matrix $E $ by

$ E = \begin{bmatrix} I_{(n-2) \times (n-2)} && 0_{(n-2) \times 2} \\ 0_{2 \times (n-2)} && R_{22} \end{bmatrix} $

Then we have $w_2 = E w_1 $

Recalling the $y= G w_1 $ and $y_1 = G w_2$ then we can write

$y_1 = G E w_1 = G E G^T y $

Hence the rotation matrix relating $y$ and $y_1$ is $R = G E G^T$

Thus, there are infinite rotation matrices $R$ that can rotate a given vector $y$ to become orthogonal to another given vector $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Not too familiar with matrix algebra but your first problem I can certainly solve. The answer is:

$$ \frac{y \times x}{|x| \sin \theta}$$

You may check that this is the result expression above can be geometrically visualized as 'twisting' $y$ ninty degrees about the line define by $x$ after killing of the component of $y$ along $x$. To restore the length to the original case we bring in the scaling factor in the denominator.

For the case of matrix, we can consider this rotation aspect of cross product to be realized as a matrix by the method described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Conversion_to_matrix_multiplication)

Comment: The user asks for a matrix, but (under normal interpretation?) this is just a vector, isn't it?  How'd you intend it to be interpreted as a matrix?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Conversion_to_matrix_multiplication

You can associate the cross product with a matrix multiplication@rschwieb

Comment: it appears so, thanks.

Comment: Does this work for any dimensions of $x$? Or only for 3D vectors?

Comment: I only have visualized the answer in 3D but perhaps all the dimensions that cross product exist in would be the answer @Physics_Student